# Google-Maps Category Filter not Working - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-filter

I have a list of cities and some or their features shown in the code below (id, city, description, latitude, longitude and icon).

I would like to filter by description as show in the examples below:

- If select 'World This city is live' is selected, dropdown list  map should
  display: *Toronto, Los Angeles and Las Vegas*;
- If 'coastal area' gets selected, dropdown list  map should display: 
  *New York and Los Angeles*;
- If 'incredible city' gets selected, dropdown list  map should display: 
  *Los Angeles*.

**My Angularjs code:**

```js
 angular.module('mapsApp', [])
        .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $compile) {
            var cities = [{
                id: '02jdjd',
                city: 'Toronto',
                desc: 'World Largest city,This city is live,This is the second best city in the world',
    lat: 43.7000,
                long: -79.4000,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsss',
                city: 'New York',
    desc: 'coastal area,This city is aiiiiite, ',
                lat: 40.6700,
                long: -73.9400,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsssws',
                city: 'Chicago',
    desc: 'This is the second best city in the world',
                lat: 41.8819,
                long: -87.6278,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsssz',
                city: 'Los Angeles',
    desc: 'This city is live,coastal area,incredible city',
                lat: 34.0500,
                long: -118.2500,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdssq',
                city: 'Las Vegas',
    desc: 'the most populous city,This city is live,This city is aiiiiite',
                lat: 36.0800,
                long: -115.1522,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'
            }];

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            $scope.markers = [];

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var createMarker = function(info) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                    title: info.city,
     icon: info.icon
                });
                marker.content = '<div><h2>'+marker.title+'</h2><input type="button" value="get" ng-click="get(\'' + info.id + '\')"/>' + '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.city + '</div></div>';
                // marker.content = "<div><h2>" + marker.title + "</h2><input type='button' value='get' ng-click='get(" + info.id + ")'/>" + "<div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.desc + "</div><div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.city + "</div></div>";
                google.maps.event.addListener(
                    marker,
                    'click', (function(marker, $scope) {
                        return function() {
                            var compiled = $compile(marker.content)($scope);
                            $scope.$apply();
                            infoWindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
                            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                        };
                    })(marker, $scope)
                );

                $scope.markers.push(marker);
            }
            $scope.get = function(city) {
                console.log(city);
                //alert("from $scope.get id : "+id); 
            }
            for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                createMarker(cities[i]);
            }

            $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
                e.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
            }




            $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
                    $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                $scope.markers.length = 0;
            }



            $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
                //1.select filtered cities
                var filteredCities;
                var cityDesc = $scope.data.singleSelect;
                if (cityDesc == '0') {
                    filteredCities = cities;
                } else {
                    filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c) {
                        if (c.desc == cityDesc)
                            return c;
                    });
                }
                //2.update markers on map
                $scope.clearMarkers();
                for (i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(filteredCities[i]);
                }
            }

        }]);

**My CSS code:**
```

```css
#map {
        height: 420px;
        width: 600px;
    }
    
    .infoWindowContent {
        font-size: 14px !important;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

**My HTML code:**
```

```html
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Filter Marker </label>
        <br>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers()">
            <option value="0">all</option>
            <option value="This is the best city in the world">This is the best city in the world</option>
            <option value="This city is aiiiiite">This city is aiiiiite</option>
            <option value="the most populous city">the most populous city</option>
            <option value="This city is live">This city is live</option>
   <option value="coastal area">coastal area</option>
   <option value="World Largest city">World Largest city</option>
   <option value="incredible city">incredible city</option>
   
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
            <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Have you any idea on why it isn't working? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering does not behave as expected since in the current implementation of `filterMarkers` function the *precise* filter is used:

```
filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c) {
   if (c.desc == cityDesc)
       return c;
});
```

Replace `filterMarkers` function with:

```
$scope.filterMarkers = function() {
    //1.select filtered cities
    var filteredCities;
    var cityDesc = $scope.data.singleSelect;
    if (cityDesc == '0') {
        filteredCities = cities;
    } else {
        filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c) {
           if (c.desc.indexOf(cityDesc) > -1) //
                        return c;
           });
        }
        //2.update markers on map
        $scope.clearMarkers();
        for (i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                createMarker(filteredCities[i]);
        }
   }
```

that returns any cities those `desc` property contains selected option value.

[**Modified example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/66frywny/)

Comment: thanks here how can i add find me .for example guset click one button map should show his/her current location with some marker icon

Comment: @martin, isn't it the same question that has been [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837333/1375553)?